# I upgraded C++ projects from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015 still its showing Visual Studio (2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

*[The configuration  window image. Just click on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOQTj.jpg)*

I upgraded C++ projects from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015, but it's still showing *(Visual Studio 2010)* in the Solution Explorer.

Please inform me if there is any change I need to do to solve this error.

This is displayed in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it simply means that the project is using the toolkit that came with Visual Studio 2010. This doesn't prevent your projects from being compiled however.

To upgrade the project to the Visual Studio 2015 toolkit right click on the projects showing (Visual Studio 2010) and select the desired toolkit under General->Platform Toolset.

[image]

Comment: there is no platform tool set  dependence for this project

Comment: @BharatD I don't believe you. Be sure you are under Configuration Properties->General.

Comment: I uploaded another Image above please refer this

Comment: Try this: click on _Configuration type_, change _Makefile_ to _Application (.exe)_, click on _Apply_, set the _Platform Toolset_ to whatever suits you (e.g. _Visual Studio 2015 (v140)_), click on _Configuration type_, change back to _Makefile_.

Comment: man i got the platform toolset i changed to v140 but still its showing visual studio 2010 for c++projects @ Michael Walz

Comment: hai man i upgraded the project toolset to v140 but still its showing visual studio 2010 for my c++ projects

Comment: there is any need to do any other changes in properties window